# Pytest: no tests ran

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have the following class file and a corresponding test file

**dir.py**:

```
import os


class Dir:
    def __init__(self, path=''):
        self.path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @path.setter
    def path(self, path):
        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        if abspath.exists():
            self._path = path
        else:
            raise IOError(f'{path} does not exist')
```

and **dir_test.py**:

```
import unittest

from ..dir import Dir


class TestDir(unittest.TestCase):

    def IOErrorIfPathNotExists(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IOError):
            Dir.path = "~/invalidpath/"
        with self.assertRaises(IOError):
            Dir('~/invalidpath/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

but when I run

```
pytest -x dir_test.py
```

it just prints `no tests ran in 0.01 seconds`

and I have no idea why.  It is my first time using pytest except with exercises from [exercism.io](http://exercism.io), and I can't spot any difference to their test files.

I am running it in a virtual environment (Python 3.6.5), with `pytest` and `pytest-cache` installed via `pip`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your test method is not named properly.

> By default, pytest will consider any class prefixed with `Test` as a test collection.

Yours is `TestDir`, this matches.

> By default, pytest will consider any function prefixed with `test` as a test.

Yours is `IOErrorIfPathNotExists`, which does not start with `test` and is not executed.

[Source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_functions).